# Avoiding repeating algorithm

Tags: php

Let's imagine that class:

```
Class Foo {

   function1($p1, $p2)
  {
    do_common_thing1()
    specific_1($p1)
    specific_2($p2)
    do_common_thing2()
  }
  function2($p1)
  {
    do_common_thing1()
    specific_3($p1)
    do_common_thing2()
  }
  /**   ...    */
  function99()
  {
    do_common_thing1()
    specific_999()
    do_common_thing2()
  }
}
```

How can I code the class to avoid repeating the common function in each method?
I've heard of the template method pattern but it seems like it can't apply to ALL my methods

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
protected function doWithCommon($func) {
    do_common_thing1();
    $func();
    do_common_thing2();
}

public function func1() {
    $this->doWithCommon(function() {
        // specific
    });
}
```